# Can't connect to ASP.Net site in Docker for Windows

Tags: docker, docker-network, docker-for-windows

I am having difficulty connecting from the host to an ASP.Net website running in a Windows container on Docker.  I can connect to a website running in a Linux container without any problem.

I have tried connecting to both localhost and to the IP port assigned to the container but in both cases I just get a timeout error.

I have tried several ASP.Net examples which are already pre-built along with trying to build my own custom image. In every case I get the same timeout error.  I have also tried uninstalling and re-installing docker but that didn't change anything.

I am running Windows 10 Pro and Docker Community Edition Version 17.03.1-ce-win12 (12058)

Comment: You can not connect to IP:port on the same host from Windows machine, you have to connect to internal IP. This is known bug on Windows. To verify it connect to your container from external machine and it shall work with IP of your workstation and port.

Comment: I have tried connecting to the internal IP of the container and it does not work.  I get the IP by using:
`docker inspect --format '{{ .NetworkSettings.Networks.nat.IPAddress }}' my-container-name`

Comment: Does it work locally within container itself? Try `Invoke-WebRequest` directl to local host.

Comment: It does work locally.  Invoke-WebRequest returns statuscode 200 and expected headers.

Comment: Disable firewall on your host

Comment: Disabling the firewall has no change.

Comment: Can you ping private IP of the container from host?

Comment: No. I can't ping the private IP of the container.

Comment: Something screwed up with container networking. Go through this article (towards the bottom) to reset container networks. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/virtualization/windowscontainers/manage-containers/container-networking

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/144885/discussion-between-joe-brinkman-and-gsa).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ultimately I was able to completely reset my container network using a customized older version of the Microsoft Vitualization cleanup scripts. https://github.com/Microsoft/Virtualization-Documentation/tree/live/windows-server-container-tools/CleanupContainerHostNetworking This reset my container network and everything is now working as expected.

Answer (score 0):

**SUMMARY:**

- *When the published port/s for a container are defined using the `EXPOSE` directive in the container's Dockerfile, the `-P` argument must be used with the `docker run` command in order to "activate" those exposed port/s.*
- *It is not possible for a Windows container host to access containers that it is running using `localhost`, `127.0.0.1` or its external host IP address. Access containers running on a given host, A, by using the IP address of A from a second host, B. Alternatively, you can use the IP address of a container directly.*

**FULL EXPLANATION:**

So there are a few nuances with ensuring that the proper firewall rules are created, and your containers are actually accessible on their published port/s.

For instance, I'll assume that your ASP.Net containerized application is defined by a container image, which was defined by a Dockerfile. **If so, you probably defined the published port for the image/app using the Dockerfile [EXPOSE](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#expose) directive.** In this case, when you actually run the container you need to "activate" that published port using the "-P" argument to the `docker run` command.

For example, if your container image is `web_app`, and the Dockerfile for that image included the line, `EXPOSE 80`, then when you go ahead and run that image you need to do something like:

```
    C:\> docker run -P web_app
```

Once the container is running, it should be available on container port 80. You can then go ahead and view the app via browser. To do that you have two options:

1. **You can access the app from your container host, *using the container IP and port***

   Find the container IP using `docker network inspect nat`, then looking for the endpoint/IP address that corresponds with your container.

   You can also fund the container IP by running `docker exec <CONTAINER ID> ipconfig`, where `<CONTAINER ID>` is the ID of your container.

   You can get the ID of your container and the exposed port for your container by running `docker ps` on the container host.
2. **You can access the app from another host machine, *using the container host IP and host port***

   You can find the IP address of your host using `ipconfig`.

   You can identify the host port upon which your app is exposed, by running `docker ps` from the host. Then, under `PORTS` you'll see a mapping of the form `0.0.0.0:<HOST PORT>-><CONTAINER PORT>/TCP`. In this mapping `<HOST PORT>`, is the port upon which your app is available on the host.

   Once you have the IP address of your container host, and the port upon which your app is available on the host, you can use that information to access your app from a browser *on a separate host*.

   **NOTE:** Today you cannot access a container in this way from its own host--currently a Windows container host cannot access the containers it is running, despite whether `localhost`, `127.0.0.1` or the host IP address is used.

Comment: Everything you have said is true, but didn't address the issue I was having.  I could not ping nor could I connect to the internal IP of any container running in Windows Containers.  Also, there is no need to designate the -P option if you are connecting to the internal IP address of the container.

Comment: I still think it is utter madness to not have working loopback in Docker for Windows. It takes the value of Docker from High to very low because there is no way to easily setup a local development environment.

Even just getting the container IP address is a pain in the ass.

Comment: Thanks for this feedback--we understand that this is an issue, and on the Windows Core Networking team we're actively working to get localhost/loopback supported on Windows. I can't provide a specific availability date at this time, but we do appreciate comments like this as validation that producing this support needs to remain a priority for our team.